# How to get the number of mail read and unread or sent and received with gmali-api?

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I want to use python to know how many emails have been sent and how many have been received.

```
label_id_one = 'INBOX'
label_id_two = 'UNREAD'
# Getting all the unread messages from Inbox
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=[label_id_one, label_id_two]).execute()
```

When I use this code,I can get the count of unread mails from inbox.

But how to get the count of readed mails?

Use the count of all mails minus unread mails?I don't think that's good.

I queried the API at this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/), but no API provided such data.

How can I get such data?

Comment: What do you mean sent or revived.  You just want a count of how many emails are on a users account?   Or how many emails are in their sent folder?

Comment: @DaImTo I want to know how many emails I sent and received with my mailbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think the information you are looking for exists.  The closest thing would be [Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)

which has a field in the response

> messagesTotal  integer The total number of messages in the mailbox.

```
{
 "emailAddress": "me@gmail.com",
 "messagesTotal": 66617,
 "threadsTotal": 14010,
 "historyId": "4618566"
}
```

However as soon as you delete a message the data is going to change and you will have one less total massages.

As far as messages sent you could do a message.list and search for the messages in the sent folder and get the result back for that but thats going to be the messages you sent since you last cleaned out that folder.

**Answer:** There is no data in the gmail api that states how many emails you have sent or received in the lifetime of your gmail account. The closest thing you could get would be

- Sent: the number of messages in your sent folder (in:sent)
- Received: the number of messages on your account that are not in your sent folder. (not in:sent)

which would change as soon as you deleted a message.

Tip: [search messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

Check Not read  `not in:sent label:unread`

**unread messages**

```
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='not in:sent label:unread').execute()
```

**read messages**

```
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me', q='not in:sent label:read').execute()
```

Comment: I saw the method you said,but I don't know what the `messagesTotal` and `messagesTotal` means?
When I delete a mail,the `messagesTotal` and `messagesTotal` will minus one?

Comment: Yes messagestotal will be one less than it was before.

Comment: But I still can't get the count of readed or unread mails.
Do I need to use the logic `Use the count of all mails minus unread mails`I said to calculate it?

Comment: I think you could do a file.list and then do **not in:sent label:unread** that should give you a list of the messages that are unread that are not in your sent folder.  Check edit

Comment: This is very helpful.

Comment: I have a query. How will you send this Unread message count to your bell icon??? Supposedly I want to display Unread count with a badge over the bell icon. How can I do this???